# New PocketSphinx user: "Segmentation fault: 11" error upon following official getting started guide

Tags: c, shell, cmusphinx, pocketsphinx

I am a new PocketSphinx user. I just followed the [official getting started guide](https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/tutorialpocketsphinx/)

However, I begin having difficulties when I get to this step:
"To test the installation, run pocketsphinx_continuous -inmic yes and check that it recognizes words you speak into your microphone."

I've attached my terminal output that I receive when I type this command, which ultimately results in 'Segmentation fault: 11'
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks,
Nakul

```
    nakul : ~ 101 $ pocketsphinx_continuous -inmic yes
INFO: pocketsphinx.c(152): Parsed model-specific feature parameters from /usr/local/share/pocketsphinx/model/en-us/en-us/feat.params
Current configuration:
[NAME] [DEFLT] [VALUE]
-agc none none
-agcthresh 2.0 2.000000e+00
-allphone 
-allphone_ci no no
-alpha 0.97 9.700000e-01
-ascale 20.0 2.000000e+01
-aw 1 1
-backtrace no no
-beam 1e-48 1.000000e-48
-bestpath yes yes
-bestpathlw 9.5 9.500000e+00
-ceplen 13 13
-cmn live batch
-cmninit 40,3,-1 41.00,-5.29,-0.12,5.09,2.48,-4.07,-1.37,-1.78,-5.08,-2.05,-6.45,-1.42,1.17
-compallsen no no
-debug 0
-dict /usr/local/share/pocketsphinx/model/en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict
-dictcase no no
-dither no no
-doublebw no no
-ds 1 1
-fdict 
-feat 1s_c_d_dd 1s_c_d_dd
-featparams 
-fillprob 1e-8 1.000000e-08
-frate 100 100
-fsg 
-fsgusealtpron yes yes
-fsgusefiller yes yes
-fwdflat yes yes
-fwdflatbeam 1e-64 1.000000e-64
-fwdflatefwid 4 4
-fwdflatlw 8.5 8.500000e+00
-fwdflatsfwin 25 25
-fwdflatwbeam 7e-29 7.000000e-29
-fwdtree yes yes
-hmm /usr/local/share/pocketsphinx/model/en-us/en-us
-input_endian little little
-jsgf 
-keyphrase 
-kws 
-kws_delay 10 10
-kws_plp 1e-1 1.000000e-01
-kws_threshold 1 1.000000e+00
-latsize 5000 5000
-lda 
-ldadim 0 0
-lifter 0 22
-lm /usr/local/share/pocketsphinx/model/en-us/en-us.lm.bin
-lmctl 
-lmname 
-logbase 1.0001 1.000100e+00
-logfn 
-logspec no no
-lowerf 133.33334 1.300000e+02
-lpbeam 1e-40 1.000000e-40
-lponlybeam 7e-29 7.000000e-29
-lw 6.5 6.500000e+00
-maxhmmpf 30000 30000
-maxwpf -1 -1
-mdef 
-mean 
-mfclogdir 
-min_endfr 0 0
-mixw 
-mixwfloor 0.0000001 1.000000e-07
-mllr 
-mmap yes yes
-ncep 13 13
-nfft 512 512
-nfilt 40 25
-nwpen 1.0 1.000000e+00
-pbeam 1e-48 1.000000e-48
-pip 1.0 1.000000e+00
-pl_beam 1e-10 1.000000e-10
-pl_pbeam 1e-10 1.000000e-10
-pl_pip 1.0 1.000000e+00
-pl_weight 3.0 3.000000e+00
-pl_window 5 5
-rawlogdir 
-remove_dc no no
-remove_noise yes yes
-remove_silence yes yes
-round_filters yes yes
-samprate 16000 1.600000e+04
-seed -1 -1
-sendump 
-senlogdir 
-senmgau 
-silprob 0.005 5.000000e-03
-smoothspec no no
-svspec 0-12/13-25/26-38
-tmat 
-tmatfloor 0.0001 1.000000e-04
-topn 4 4
-topn_beam 0 0
-toprule 
-transform legacy dct
-unit_area yes yes
-upperf 6855.4976 6.800000e+03
-uw 1.0 1.000000e+00
-vad_postspeech 50 50
-vad_prespeech 20 20
-vad_startspeech 10 10
-vad_threshold 2.0 2.000000e+00
-var 
-varfloor 0.0001 1.000000e-04
-varnorm no no
-verbose no no
-warp_params 
-warp_type inverse_linear inverse_linear
-wbeam 7e-29 7.000000e-29
-wip 0.65 6.500000e-01
-wlen 0.025625 2.562500e-02
INFO: feat.c(715): Initializing feature stream to type: '1s_c_d_dd', ceplen=13, CMN='batch', VARNORM='no', AGC='none'
INFO: acmod.c(162): Using subvector specification 0-12/13-25/26-38
INFO: mdef.c(518): Reading model definition: /usr/local/share/pocketsphinx/model/en-us/en-us/mdef
INFO: mdef.c(531): Found byte-order mark BMDF, assuming this is a binary mdef file
INFO: bin_mdef.c(336): Reading binary model definition: /usr/local/share/pocketsphinx/model/en-us/en-us/mdef
INFO: bin_mdef.c(516): 42 CI-phone, 137053 CD-phone, 3 emitstate/phone, 126 CI-sen, 5126 Sen, 29324 Sen-Seq
INFO: tmat.c(149): Reading HMM transition probability matrices: /usr/local/share/pocketsphinx/model/en-us/en-us/transition_matrices
INFO: acmod.c(113): Attempting to use PTM computation module
INFO: ms_gauden.c(127): Reading mixture gaussian parameter: /usr/local/share/pocketsphinx/model/en-us/en-us/means
INFO: ms_gauden.c(242): 42 codebook, 3 feature, size: 
INFO: ms_gauden.c(244): 128x13
INFO: ms_gauden.c(244): 128x13
INFO: ms_gauden.c(244): 128x13
INFO: ms_gauden.c(127): Reading mixture gaussian parameter: /usr/local/share/pocketsphinx/model/en-us/en-us/variances
INFO: ms_gauden.c(242): 42 codebook, 3 feature, size: 
INFO: ms_gauden.c(244): 128x13
INFO: ms_gauden.c(244): 128x13
INFO: ms_gauden.c(244): 128x13
INFO: ms_gauden.c(304): 222 variance values floored
INFO: ptm_mgau.c(476): Loading senones from dump file /usr/local/share/pocketsphinx/model/en-us/en-us/sendump
INFO: ptm_mgau.c(500): BEGIN FILE FORMAT DESCRIPTION
INFO: ptm_mgau.c(563): Rows: 128, Columns: 5126
INFO: ptm_mgau.c(595): Using memory-mapped I/O for senones
INFO: ptm_mgau.c(838): Maximum top-N: 4
INFO: phone_loop_search.c(114): State beam -225 Phone exit beam -225 Insertion penalty 0
INFO: dict.c(320): Allocating 138824 * 32 bytes (4338 KiB) for word entries
INFO: dict.c(333): Reading main dictionary: /usr/local/share/pocketsphinx/model/en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict
INFO: dict.c(213): Dictionary size 134723, allocated 1016 KiB for strings, 1679 KiB for phones
INFO: dict.c(336): 134723 words read
INFO: dict.c(358): Reading filler dictionary: /usr/local/share/pocketsphinx/model/en-us/en-us/noisedict
INFO: dict.c(213): Dictionary size 134728, allocated 0 KiB for strings, 0 KiB for phones
INFO: dict.c(361): 5 words read
INFO: dict2pid.c(396): Building PID tables for dictionary
INFO: dict2pid.c(406): Allocating 42^3 * 2 bytes (144 KiB) for word-initial triphones
INFO: dict2pid.c(132): Allocated 42672 bytes (41 KiB) for word-final triphones
INFO: dict2pid.c(196): Allocated 42672 bytes (41 KiB) for single-phone word triphones
INFO: ngram_model_trie.c(354): Trying to read LM in trie binary format
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(74): Initializing search tree
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(101): 791 unique initial diphones
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(186): Creating search channels
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(323): Max nonroot chan increased to 152609
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(333): Created 723 root, 152481 non-root channels, 53 single-phone words
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(157): fwdflat: min_ef_width = 4, max_sf_win = 25
INFO: continuous.c(307): pocketsphinx_continuous COMPILED ON: Sep 6 2018, AT: 19:28:29
INFO: continuous.c(252): Ready....
Segmentation fault: 11
nakul : ~ 102 $ defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES.
```

Comment: Make sure you compile for the debug version. Then start the program in Visual Studio. There is a good chance VS will stop at the fault location so you can examine what is wrong.

Comment: Could you elaborate on compiling for the debug version? I am newer at this sort of stuff. I use VS Code as my IDE.